# Recreate schema_migrations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

When I upgraded my version of ruby, i had to reinstall my gems. Somewhere down the line it completely cleared out my database for my project.

I cant run

```
rake db:migrate
```

because i no longer have a schema_migrations table. But when I go to create a new table I get this error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'schema_migrations' (errno: 13)
Please check privileges of directory containing database.
```

How can I go about recreating this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I had to delete my schema.rb file and create a new database and change my database.yml file to connect to that one instead. Then I ran `rake db:migrate` and it created the schema_migrations table and continued migrating back to my old state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `bundle install` yet?

Comment: If your `schema.rb` is still around, just do a `rake db:schema:load`

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the directory?

Comment: yes its still returning the error that there is now schema_migrations table